# how to add 0 digit to a single symbol hex value where it is missed, bash

Tags: bash

I have a some file with the following content

```
$ cat somefile
28 46 5d a2 26 7a 192 168 2 2  
0 15 e c8 a8 a3 192 168 100 3
54 4 2b 8 c 26 192 168 20 3
```

As you can see the values in first six columns are represented in hex, the values in last four columns in decimal formats. I just want to add 0 to every single symbol hexidecimal value.

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You mean you want the second line to be like: `00 15 0e c8 a8 a3 192 168 100 3`?

Comment: Not efficient though, but you can iterate through all the numbers and if you find a number made of single digit for the first 6 columns append 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way with `awk` if that is an option:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=6;i++) if(length($i)<2) $i=0$i}1' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
28 46 5d a2 26 7a 192 168 2 2  
0 15 e c8 a8 a3 192 168 100 3
54 4 2b 8 c 26 192 168 20 3
```

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=6;i++) if(length($i)<2) $i=0$i}1' file
28 46 5d a2 26 7a 192 168 2 2  
00 15 0e c8 a8 a3 192 168 100 3
54 04 2b 08 0c 26 192 168 20 3
```

Answer (score 3):

This one should work out for you:

```
while read -a line
do
    hex=(${line[@]:0:6})
    printf "%02x " ${hex[@]/#/0x}
    echo ${line[@]:6:4}
done < somefile
```

Example:

```
$ cat somefile 
28 46 5d a2 26 7a 192 168 2 2  
0 15 e c8 a8 a3 192 168 100 3
54 4 2b 8 c 26 192 168 20 3
```

```
$ while read -a line
> do
>     hex=(${line[@]:0:6})
>     printf "%02x " ${hex[@]/#/0x}
>     echo ${line[@]:6:4}
> done < somefile
28 46 5d a2 26 7a 192 168 2 2
00 15 0e c8 a8 a3 192 168 100 3
54 04 2b 08 0c 26 192 168 20 3
```

Comment: I tried the first one, Its just adding whitespace to single symbol values, so results become something  like this :( </br>
- 28 46 5d a2 26 7a 192 168 2 2 </br> 
-  0 15  e c8 a8 a3 192 168 100 3 </br>
- 54  4 2b  8  c 26 192 168 20 3 </br>

Comment: Are you sure about that?  I tested that here.  I can provide some sample output if you want.

Comment: @azatuni: It works for me on `GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)`. What version of Bash are you running? (As in -- what does `bash --version` print?)

Comment: I'm using an ancient bash (I'm on a Mac).  Both of these answers should work in any reasonable version.

Comment: bash verison is 4.2.39(1)-release

Comment: That input doesn't match what you said you had in your question.

Comment: Looks like a bash version change; `%02s` doesn't work the same in bash 4.2.  I'll make an update shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this too, if it helps (bash version 4.1.7(1)-release)

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line;do
  arr=($line)

  i=0
  for num in "${arr[@]}";do
     if [ $i -lt 6 ];then
         if [ ${#num} -eq 1 ];then
             arr[i]='0'${arr[i]};
         fi
     fi
     i=$((i+1))

  done
  echo "${arr[*]}"
done<your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for  you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\b\S\s/0&/g' file
```

Finds a single non-space character and prepends a `0`.